# parsing wikimedia api

Tags: python, xml, regex, mediawiki

I need your help. I'm parsing wikipedia article and using  Wikimedia api.  I want to read the text between `{{ }}`. Here is my [wikimedia api query](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=xmlfm&titles=papori&rvsection=0). I tried but not  found any luck. can any one please help me ? thank you so much.

```
def getCategory(title):
paramsd = {'action': 'query', 'prop': 'revisions', 'rvprop': 'content', 'format': 'xmlfm', 'rvsection': 0,'titles':title}
params = urllib.urlencode(paramsd)
req = urllib2.Request(url='http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php', data=params)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Comment: *“You are looking at the HTML representation of the XML format. HTML is good for debugging, but probably is not suitable for your application.”* – should give you already a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know, there are a few libraries already written for this exact purpose, in python there's pywikipedia, and there are more for every language ever. There's a list at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#API_Access_Libraries that lists four libraries for python. I'd use one of those instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code.

```
'format': 'xmlfm'
```

Should read

```
'format': 'xml'
```

That way, you'll get back XML.